# The use of the sentence structures "there is"/there are" in context

Tags: grammar

Tell me please if the following sentence is correct.

> John asked me if I had something to eat and I told him that **there were eggs**.

Is it necessary to specify where those eggs are? For example:

> There are eggs in the kitchen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say your sentence is incorrect, and no, you don't need to specify the location of the eggs.

That said, some might agree that this version reads a little less awkwardly than your original:

> John asked me if I had something to eat and I told him that **we had** eggs.

Comment: I'm surprised such an experienced user accepted this answer within a mere 15 minutes. As a reminder, we encourage the community to wait [half a day](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) or so.